# SKStreetType - which types are actually highways?

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

```
SKStreetTypeUndefined = 0,
SKStreetTypeBridleway = 1,
SKStreetTypeConstruction = 2,
SKStreetTypeCrossing = 3,
SKStreetTypeCycleway = 4,
SKStreetTypeFerry = 5,
SKStreetTypeFootway = 6,
SKStreetTypeFord = 7,
SKStreetTypeLiving_street = 8,
SKStreetTypeMotorway = 9,
SKStreetTypeMotorway_link = 10,
SKStreetTypePath = 11,
SKStreetTypePedestrian = 12,
SKStreetTypePrimary = 13,
SKStreetTypePrimary_link = 14,
SKStreetTypeResidential = 15,
SKStreetTypeRoad = 16,
SKStreetTypeSecondary = 17,
SKStreetTypeSecondary_link = 18,
SKStreetTypeService = 19,
SKStreetTypeSteps = 20,
SKStreetTypeTertiary = 21,
SKStreetTypeTertiary_link = 22,
SKStreetTypeTrack = 23,
SKStreetTypeTrunk = 24,
SKStreetTypeTrunk_link = 25,
SKStreetTypeUnclassified = 26,
SKStreetTypeFerryPed = 310,
SKStreetTypeResidential_limited = 311,
SKStreetTypeUnpavedTrack = 377,
SKStreetTypePermissive = 378,
SKStreetTypeDestination = 379,
SKStreetTypePier = 380
```

Out of all these types of road, I would assume only

```
SKStreetTypeMotorway = 9
```

and maybe

```
SKStreetTypeMotorway_link = 10
```

Can be accounted as highways.
I have no other way of checking that than posting it here, but maybe I missed out on some street type and I have to know for sure

Comment: Seems like the only way to know is to ask the people who actually made the framework...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OSM terminology (on which this enum is based) defines [highway = motorway](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:highway%3Dmotorway) as the way of marking highways/motorways so yes, SKStreetTypeMotorway indicates a highway/motorway/autobahn. (In general, since the Scout SDK uses OpenStreetMap as a default map data source, a lot of the internal structures follow the OpenStreetMap tagging system, so when in doubt, check the OSM terminology).

SKStreetTypeMotorway_link describes the access roads/ramps onto or off the highway - while it can be considered to be part of the highway, it's not the same thing as a highway.

[image]